# How do i Dynamically load UserControls the correct way?

Tags: user-controls, dotnetnuke, portal

im basically creating a portal system, and want to load UserControls Dynamically, now i have read a couple of articles on this where they loading them into a placeholder, i have tried this. but it just seems a little buggy. its there not a better way to manage the viewstate etc

how does dotnetnuke do it where they inject the controls into regions/tablecells? and then how is the viewstate managed?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any DNN expereience, however if you do

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
    var control = UserControl.LoadControl("control.ascx");
    Page.Controls.Add(control);
}
```

This will load the control dynamically and add it to the page. You want to make sure you do it `OnInit` so that the control exists before viewstate is loaded. This way viewstate will be handed automatically.

Comment: thanks, by saying that, do usercontrols manage thier own viewstate? and this would then work by adding multiple usercontrols to the page correct?

Comment: It depenends on exactly what is in your `UserControl` If your `UserControl` contains standard ASP.NET Controls which manage their own ViewState then yes. If you have special values which need to be stored, the `UserControl` must impliment that themself.